# DDoS throttling vs deny actions

Tags: ddos, countermeasure

Recently I saw the Google Report about the DDoS Attack that they managed to stop. In the report, [they said](https://ttps://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/how-google-cloud-blocked-largest-layer-7-ddos-attack-at-46-million-rps),

> "They chose the ‘**throttle**’ action over a ‘**deny**’ action in
> order to reduce chance of impact on legitimate traffic while severely
> limiting the attack capability by dropping most of the attack volume
> at Google’s network edge."

Can you explain to me the differences between the throttling action and the deny action? In the report, the explanation is quite vague for my understanding.

PS: I am familiar with deny type of action, but I never encountered the throttling term.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.google.com/search?q=ddos+throttling

Comment: It helps yes, new information to analyze. By the way, thanks for editing, it's my first time posting :) Also, English is not my first language, so there might be some misplaced words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, "throttling" something means slowing down performance, while "denying" means the request gets no response.

Typically, *denying* is used when it is clear that the perpetrators are in a set of malicious nodes. While is is very effective at reducing the impact of the DDoS attack, it also requires that you can tell malicious and benign nodes apart. Otherwise, you'd block legitimate nodes from using your service.

*Throttling* is used when you can't quite tell legitimate from malicious nodes. Essentially, you reduce the amount of resources each node gets (e.g. bandwidth), so each node gets slower responses. This reduces the impact on your service (thus mitigating the DDoS attack), while also not completely denying your service to nodes, which may or may not be legitimate.

---

From the perspective of a malicious node, *denying* them is worse. Their impact on the target service is greatly reduced, making the DDoS attack as a whole less effective. *Throttling* is better, because the attack still does some damage.

From the perspective of a legitimate node, which is falsely identified as malicious, *denying* is worse. They just cannot use the service at all. *Throttling* is better, because even though the service is slow, it's still mostly usable.

From the perspective of a legitimate node, which has been identified as legitimate, *denying* is better, because their performance is less affected by the DDoS attack. *Throttling* is worse, because the DDoS attack still affects them somewhat.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation that you've offered. Basically this means that in different situations, each method has its own advantages and disadvantages, which is normal. I am a "nooby" in this field, so every information that is useful to me is a bonus

Comment: @aidCoder You are correct. Denying is more useful when you can clearly tell malicious nodes apart from benign nodes. Throttling is more useful when such a distinction is not possible or prone to errors. I hope it helps.